# Ubuntu windows dual boot with ubuntu on sata ssd and windows in hdd caddy

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, grub-efi, grub-legacy

I want my ubuntu ( or any other linux) on my sata ssd and windows on my HDD Caddy. Is it possible?
If yes what's the procedure?
How to configure GRUB?
Why i want this?
Well, i dont have large ssd or hdd.
So cant partition. Gonna do experiments on both OS. So, i want one functional OS at a time.

Dell latitude e6420 ( 9yrs old now)
Has both legacy and uefi with latest bios update A26.

Comment: It can be done. Please run `sudo parted -l' from an Ubuntu LiveUSB, highlight & copy the text in the results, then return here, click [edit] & paste the results text into your question so we can see it. Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download or for a supported 'flavour' with a different Desktop Environment, download from https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours . Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make a LiveUSB on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 .

Comment: That's `sudo parted -l` where "l" is a lowercase L, not the number one.